# connection to db4free with php

Tags: php, database, connection, database-connection

i'm new here and doing some project,

how can i connect to my database in db4free.net from php,
i have tried this

```
<?php

$host = "db4free.net/mainbookstore";
$user = "***";
$pass = "****";
$database = "mainbookstore";

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if ($conn) {
$buka = mysql_select_db ($database);
if (!$buka) {
die ("Database tidak dapat dibuka");
}
} else {
die ("Server MySQL tidak terhubung"); 
}

?>
```

but get error Such no host, but in my java use :

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/mainbookstore");
```

i can connect to my database.
Thanks before :)

Comment: do not share your password. and why don't you use port number as well

Comment: im sorry my apologize, i just copied it, thanks :)
using port 3306 still not working

this is the error :

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\testjava\connection.php on line 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, it is the missing port. Try

```
$host = "db4free.net:3306/mainbookstore";
```

and it should work.

Comment: i have give the port and nothing change, is it problem that i run that in my localhost ? i think thats not a problem right

Comment: I've tried connecting from my local environment and everything went just fine. However, omitting the port gave me the same error (as expected)